# Network Traffic Troubleshooting Program

Tags: windows, internet

All,

I am having intermittent network issues that I am having an issue troubleshooting. The issue is outside of my network on one of the hops in my local area. I was wondering if you all knew of a good windows based program that would monitor/log a tracert or something of that nature.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to just log what is happening for later analysis? Or do you want it to log and alert you when something specific happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PingPlotter](http://www.pingplotter.com/), or [VisualRoute](http://www.visualroute.com/)
 should do the job.

Comment: Anything open source?

Comment: Ended up using VisualRoute